# Remove messaging icon from indicator plugin xfce panel Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, uninstall, xfce, email, panel

Some people don't like an email indicator on the systray (like me) and some applications don't give you this option.

Answer (score 1):

just right click on the mail icon, hit properties.

[image]

you'll see a list of indicators like: sound, power management and messaging menu. check the box on the right next to messaging menu, close. log out, log back in and there, the icon should be gone. this hides the indicator instead of removing or deleting it which most of the times will result in issues with the panel. 
 I don't know if it's the same for Ubuntu. let me know if this worked for you.